# CiviCRM video courses

Tags: installation, usability, training

CiviCRM is a great piece of software, but its reputation could be greatly improved giving video material to newcomers. Is there any project or team to involve on this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

As Erik says, there are a variety of videos available, but those are mostly recordings of events.

I agree with you that a set of videos aimed at newcomers would be useful.  A curated list of existing ones would be a start.

If that is something you have an interest in and would be willing to help with then maybe start a discussion in the ~community channel on chat.

Comment: In 5 years I have dedicated a lot of time to translating CiviCRM into Italian, I use it in an installation for the Civil Protection and I have always thought that making videos to promote the conscious use of resources would also give an impulse to better develop useful components.
I have no experience in handling such a thing, but I certainly want to continue to help, because CiviCRM deserves much more than the popularity it currently has.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question! Not sure what you expect exactly when you are asking if any team is involved in this :-) In an open source community like CiviCRM is there is no central co-ordination of activities nor are we aware of all organizations doing stuff with CiviCRM (until they communicate this within the community ofcourse).

Having said this, there are several video's around CiviCRM:

https://docs.crm-showcases.org/

https://www.youtube.com/@civicrmintkort50 (all in Dutch)

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwjTdfZDtG9dtmyC51aYKl5ta2rBmATeN

https://www.youtube.com/@CiviCRM-project